# ¿Como obtener el largo de una columna en Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola estoy trabajando en Code Igniter de php y necesito multiplicar el numero que mando desde el front con el total de datos en una columna `lenght` este tiene como nombre `id` y es auto incrementable.

intente con esto, desde model:

```
function InsertRegistro($data){

$this->db->insert('mascalo',$data);
$this->db->select_max('id');
$query = $this->db->get('mascalo');
return $query->row();
```

}

y desde el controller:

```
public function getdatoCHILE(){

$data = array(
'total' => $this->input->post('total'),
'hash' => $this->input->post('hash')
);

$this->load->model('Model_app');
$largo = $this->Model_app->InsertRegistro($data);

if ($data==null) {
  $this->_app_output($this->error);  
}

else {
        $dinero= $data['total'];
        $numero = $largo * $dinero

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($numero);
}
```

}

Ayuda please! me retorna 1 saludos.

Answer (score 1):

el problema viene del lado que $query->row(); no devuelve el máximo id si no seleccionas el campo, prueba esto:

```
function InsertRegistro($data){
    $this->db->insert('mascalo',$data);
    $this->db->select_max('id as largo');
    $query = $this->db->get('mascalo');
    $row = $query->row(); 
    return $row->largo;}
```

Comment: Como complemento podría seleccionar ` $this->db->select('COUNT(id) as largo');`, ya que la cantidad de registros no forzosamente debe ser igual al id más largo

Comment: exactamente Sergio.